# Decent way to requery CanExecute in Silverlight MVVM?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I have a simple LoginForm.

Here is how the code-behind looks like:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
  Handles btnLogin.Click
    If Me.loginForm.ValidateItem() Then
      'Do the actual login - (calling VM command)
      DirectCast(Me.DataContext, LoginViewModel).LoginCommand.Execute()
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I created a LoginViewModel that exposes a LoginCommand. I would like to keep the code-behind clean, and in the other hand, leave the ViewModel UI independent.
What should be the cleanest way to do this?

I am looking for an application level solution so I can make all the controls UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged or another workaround whatsoever to requery the CanExecute command when attempting click.

**Update** after Jon's answer:
So where should I call this method from, should it be the `Login`?

```
Private m_LoginCommand As ICommand
Public ReadOnly Property LoginCommand() As ICommand
  Get
    If m_LoginCommand Is Nothing Then m_LoginCommand =
      New DelegateCommand(AddressOf Login, AddressOf CanLogin)
    Return m_LoginCommand
  End Get
End Property
Private Function CanLogin() As Boolean
  Return Not IsLoggingIn
End Function
Private Sub Login()
  DirectCast(LoginCommand, DelegateCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
  If Not CanLogin() Then Exit Sub
  'Do login
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the type of `LoginCommand`? You should provide this information at least.

Comment: @Jon, The LoginCommand is a simple `DelegateCommand` (or `RelayCommand`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what your goal is, so I hope I got this right.

Assuming you are using Prism, then whenever `LoginCommand`'s can-execute status is changed (which is done from your ViewModel), the VM should immediately call [`RaiseCanExecuteChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommandbase.raisecanexecutechanged%28v=PandP.38%29.aspx) on it. This will notify all controls that bind to this command that they need to requery the `CanExecute` status.

If you are not using Prism, your command class should have some similar mechanism.

In any case, you don't need to do anything from the View.

Comment: That's actually something I was looking for, I just need more advise on how to use it, please read the update on my question.

Comment: @Shimmy: Call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` just after the value of `IsLoggingIn` is changed, not inside `Login`. If it's a property, do it inside the property setter.

Comment: I don't know where I should cal that `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` from. It's obviuos that it has to be called whenever user updates the fields data (the Username and Password fields), tho, Silverlight doesn't allow `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.